# Affine $k$-domain, which is also a PID and whose group of units is same as that of $k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Let $R$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra such that $R$ is a non-field PID and $R^*=k^*$ , where $R^*$ denotes the group of units of $R$. Then is it true that $R=k[f]$ for some $f \in k[X]$ i.e. $R$ is isomorphic to $k[X]$ as $k$-algebras ?

Comment: This is true, but not quite trivial (at least in my mind). Think of $R$ as the co-ordinate functions on a smooth curve and see what its projective completion is and work backwards to get what you want.

Comment: @Mohan: can you please write an elaborate proof as an answer ? Or give a reference may be ?

Comment: All details can not be given without assuming facts about the Picard group of a smooth projective curve. In particular, the fact that $\mathrm{Pic}^0$ is an abelian variety and thus a divisible group.

Comment: @Mohan : ok, you can write a proof assuming the standard known facts, and then give some references for the standard non-elementary facts at the end ? I would be happy to accept such an answer (unless someone comes up with a rather elementary proof ...)

Comment: @Mohan: btw ... just related questions ... does the claim remain valid if we drop any of the characteristic zero or f.g. algebra condition ?

Comment: @Mohan : hello ..? Can you please at least comment on my question on whether any of the assumptions of $k$ being algebraically closed, or characteristic zero or $A$ being finitely generated can be dropped ?

Comment: Algebraically closed is necessary (I believe $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$ is a counterexample otherwise), characteristic is not important, have no idea how to deal with non-finitely generated algebras.